# No option for Dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, google-app-engine

I need to create a dynamic web project in Eclipse but the option doesn't appear anymore.
I installed Google Web Apps engine(JAVA) and its SDK along with GWT, ever since the option for dynamic project has disappeared.

Also the option to generate web client from WSDL files is no longer there.
I've tried re-installing the web app toolkit for eclipse but still it's not working.

Any pointers to get back these options would be great

Thanks

Comment: the problem was GWT SDK, it had screwed up my eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Eclipse WTP plugin has been accidently removed. Have you tried re-installing WTP using [this location](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates) ? If I were you I would have reinstall Eclipse from strach or even better try [Spring ToolSuite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) which integrates with **Google Plugin for Eclipse** seamlessly (usign *Extenstions* tab on STS Dashboard)

Comment: reinstalled from scratch and this time i didn't add GWT SDK... fixed!